# Software for asset or password management in a team

Tags: password-management

At the office we are looking for software to manage, share and store several of our digital assets like software licenses, registration codes, and **most importantly passwords** for our hundreds of servers.

I know there are several software packages that already do this but our office manager asked me if there was any software that allows him to easily share some of these assets with given people/colleagues. He is tired of copy/pasting details all the time and passing the over by email or IM which is tiresome and most of all very insecure since they get passed around in plain text.

So, anyone knows of software that allows us to do this? The idea is that all colleagues get a login for the software (which probably runs on the server) and when they log in they see the assets they have access to, defined by an administrator.

Comment: Question: why do your hundreds of servers have different passwords? Why are you using LDAP or at least NIS for sign on so you don't have to manage unique passwords for every machine? And then sudo to grant/remove privileges?

Answer (score 1):

If the scale is small enough, you might consider using something like KeePass.  The biggest pro is that it is free and that it can store quite a few different types of data (I've used it for organizing passwords, keys, and certificates.)  The downside for this is that you provide all-or-nothing access to all your credentials.

Beyond that, and you're looking at something like [Thycotic's Secret Server](http://www.thycotic.com/products_secretserver_overview.html) or some offerings from [Cyber-Ark](http://www.cyber-ark.com/).  They provide much more control over access to individual authentication tokens and auditing.  This is a big help if someone leaves the company since you can track all the credentials they viewed and know which need to be changed.

You might also explore the options in [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/119892/company-password-management).

Comment: +1 for Secret Server, which starts at $500 and works pretty well. -1 for Cyber-Ark, which will cost you six figures if you're lucky.